# How do you secure deployd server dashboard

Tags: dashboard, deployd

How do you secure a deployed server dashboard? ideally with authentication.

Comment: You might wish to build on this questino. At the moment it is a bit to broad and all details are missing. Example: what server, what dashboard, what do you mean with secure int his contex etc.

Comment: Simply put, it’s a web-based IDE for Deployd configuration files. It’s an expressive interface that lets you create your app’s API visually.  its open by default  e.g  ipaddress:2404/dashboard   how do you secure it ?

Answer (score 1):

From the deployd docs:

> To set up the dashboard on your server, type `dpd keygen` on your
>   server's command line to create a remote access key. Type `dpd showkey`
>   to get the key; you should store this somewhere secure.
>
> You can then go to the `/dashboard` route on the server and type in that
>   key to gain access.

See here: http://docs.deployd.com/docs/server/your-server.md#s-Dashboard%20Access-2728

The documentation at docs.deployed.com has more detail than the github documentation by the way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this has no effect here, I never get asked to enter a key after running those commands ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Change directory (`cd`) to your Deployd project's root.
2. Run `dpd keygen`.
3. Run `dpd showkey` and save the key somewhere.
4. Restart dpd with `--environment production` option, otherwise it won't
   require the key when accessing `/dashboard`.
5. Go to your API's `/dashboard` and paste the key in the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

On top of auth, I'm also limiting it to data-entry users only.
It's not perfect (i also want to remove the delete-resource button), but here goes:

**env.sh**

```
# this makes deployd require key for /dashboard
export NODE_ENV=production
```

**.production.patch** (disables events- config-editors)

```
--- node_modules/deployd/lib/resources/dashboard/index.ejs  2016-11-21 16:10:05.406025488 +0100                                                                                               
+++ node_modules/deployd/lib/resources/dashboard/index.ejs.new  2016-11-21 16:09:51.009794524 +0100
@@ -65,7 +65,7 @@
         <a href="#" class="options"><span class="caret"></span></a>
         <% if (type && type.dashboardPages) { %>
           <ul class="nav pages type-icons <%= isCurrent ? '' : 'hide' %>">
-            <% type.dashboardPages.forEach(function(p) { %>
+            <% type.dashboardPages.forEach(function(p) { if( p.match(/Config|Events|Properties/) != null ) return %>
               <li <%- isCurrent && (Context.page || '').toLowerCase() === p.toLowerCase() ? 'class=active' : ''%>  ><a href="/dashboard/<%= resource.id %>/<%= p.toLowerCase() %>/"><i class="icon-white icon-custom <%= p.toLowerCase() %>"></i> <%= p %></a></li>
             <% }); %>
           </ul>
```

**.git/hooks/post-merge** (automatically call upon git pull)

```
#!/bin/bash

# disallow users from changing resource schema's, event-code and config.json
patch -Np0 < .production.patch

[[ ! -n $NO_NPM ]] && npm update
```